# auto convert ascii values to acutal char

Tags: c#, .net

I have a huge string and few lines of it are given bellow:

\x5b\x5b\x5b\x220B_to5Zwh_yJXV2FKdHV2N1lndk0\x22,\x5b\x220APto5Zwh_yJXUk9PVA\x22\x5d\n,\x22OfferArcade\x22,\x22application/vnd.google-apps.folder\x22,0,0,0,0,1,1420447667416,1420447667294,1420447667294,1502262110474,null,\x5b\x5b1,\x2204490703266643460813\x22,\x22Priyam Paul\x22,null,\x22//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FE82xOkpzWw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAd8/KPtKNTPPaNE/photo.jpg\x22

I am looking for a solution where it can automatically detect the ascii and convert it into the original char.

For example ascii `\x5b` is actually a `[`

So I need a solution which will automatically detect all the ascii's and convert those into the original char.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I decode a UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468026/how-should-i-decode-a-utf-8-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Regex.Unescape`

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string text = "\x5b\x5b\x5b\x220B_to5Zwh_yJXV2FKdHV2N1lndk0\x22"; //and so on
string decoded = Regex.Unescape(text);
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

**Output:**

```
[[["0B_to5Zwh_yJXV2FKdHV2N1lndk0"
```